# fund stolen from my blockchain wallet

Tags: blockchain.info, blockchain-wallet-app

I am Ashish jaiswal from India. I logged in to my blockchain wallet today and i received the approval email from blockchain. I approved the email and in next minute I see 8.43 btc has been taken out of my wallet. what shall I do?

Comment: Sorry to hear about your loss, unfortunately there is likely nothing that anyone here can do to help you. Without a lot more information, it isn't possible to say how you were hacked. You could attempt to contact blockchain(dot)com's customer service team for more help.

Comment: What "approval email" are you talking about exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It seems possible the "approval email" was a fake and that you clicked a link in that email which led to a fake website that tricked you into giving your account credentials to a thief.

> what shall I do?

Report the theft to blockchain.com and ask for their help.

Report the theft to your local police.

Accept that your money is gone and almost certainly will never be recovered.

Perhaps do some research on the differences between custodial-wallets and non-custodial wallets and on the differences between hot-wallets and cold-wallets. Investigate the prices and availability of hardware wallets.

Do not respond to unsolicited messages from people saying they can recover your money - they are conmen who will later invent false fees you need to pay them.